# Extract date from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my anchor tag

```
<a href="/availability-calendars/28/2011/12/edit?destination=node%2F28">edit</a>
```

I want to extract "2011/12" from the href in  using javascript.I don't want to use split function.

Is there any way?

Comment: Sure there are ways. Substring, slice, etc. But split would be easiest, so why not tell us why you don't want to use split?

Comment: Will the date string always be preceded by 'availability-calendars' and followed by 'edit?'

Comment: yes. It is always be preceded by 'availability-calendars' and followed by 'edit?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var matches = "/availability-calendars/28/2011/12/edit?destination=node%2F28".match(/\/([1-2][09][0-9]{2})\/([0-1]?[0-9])\//);

var year = parseFloat( matches[1] );
var month = parseFloat( matches[2] );
```

This should work for dates in the year range 1900-2099, it looks for `"/year/month/"`

The regex used:

`/\/([1-2][09][0-9]{2})\/([0-1]?[0-9])\//`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this javascript code

```
<a href="/write_pilot/availability-calendars/28/2011/12/edit?destination=node%2F28" id="ahref">Hello</a>


    <script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        str = document.getElementById('ahref').href;
        str2 = "availability-calendar";
        pos = str.indexOf(str2)+parseInt(str2.length) + 2;
        date = str.substring(parseInt(pos),parseInt(pos)+10);
        alert(date);
    }
</script>
```